# Finding missing data in Excel without having xlookup function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know how to do this using the `XLOOKUP` function, but if I don't have access to that function how would this be done?

I have columns with names and ID #'s. I have created another column with a few select ID #'s and want to find the name that matches up with the ID#. How do I find the name matching the ID# without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find the information.

I've included an example of what I'm talking about. This information was taken from an Excel training video, so the information is made up.

[image: Example of what I am talking about]

Comment: Why would you not have access to xlookup?

Comment: "Xlookup" is an easy way to deal with this problem.This function is currently available to Microsoft 365 subscribers in the Monthly channel. It will be available to Microsoft 365 subscribers in the Semi-Annual channel starting in July 2020. If you want to use it, please update your office.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(E2,$C$2:$C$14,0))
```

[image]